# Why must $\phi(1) \in H$ if $\phi$ is a deck transformation of $G$, with normal subgroup $H$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Hypothesis:** Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Let $p: G \rightarrow G/H$ form the universal covering over $G/H$. Let $\phi$ be an arbitrary deck transformation of $G$.

**Question:** Why is it that $\phi(1) \in H$?  Do we have also that, necessarily,  $\phi(1) = 1$?

Comment: $\phi(1)$ does not have to be $1$. $\phi(1) \in H$ because $p \circ \phi = p$ if $\phi$ is a deck transformation.

Comment: In fact, if $H$ is normal, then $\phi(1)$ can be any element of $H$.

Comment: @Siddharth That should be an answer, I think.

Comment: I will make that an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a deck transformation, then by definition, $p \circ \phi = p.$ Hence, $p(\phi(1)) = 1H$, and hence $\phi(1) \in H.$

On the other hand, the universal cover is always a regular covering space and hence, the space of deck transformations act transitively on the fiber of any point. Hence, since the fiber above $1H$ is all of $H$, for any $h \in H$, there is a deck transformation $\phi$ such that $\phi(1) = h.$

Comment: For the first part, is the argument that $p(\phi(1)) = p(1) = 1H$?  If so, why is it that $p(1) = 1H$?

Comment: Because $p$ just sends an element $g \in G$ to $gH \in G/H.$